# Выбор из базы по максимальной дате у ID

Tags: php, mysql

Есть mySQL таблица с списком задач

```
id | mid | s | e | date 
1  | 15  | 1 | 3 | 2017-01-17 00:00:00 
2  | 15  | 1 | 4 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 
3  | 20  | 2 | 6 | 2017-01-23 00:00:00 
4  | 20  | 2 | 7 | 2017-02-02 00:00:00 
5  | 20  | 2 | 8 | 2017-02-07 00:00:00 
6  | 34  | 3 | 5 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00
```

Стоит задача выбрать строки в которых максимальная дата заканчивается в течении двух недель. То есть из варианта выше необходимо получить mid 15 и 34
Критерий выборки максимальная дата у каждого уникального mid не должна превышать сегодня + 2 недели, если максимальная дата у mid выше сегодня + 2 недели то такой mid пропускаем. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Подскажите с чего начать, что то ни как не соображу как получить такие данные. Пробовал запросы и с group by и с DISTINCT но все они не делали что нужно.

Или же проще брать все данные и на PHP уже отсеивать?

Comment: Начните с самого обычного запроса получения максимальной даты (MAX) у каждого (GROUP BY) mid. Продолжите отсевом записей (HAVING), которые не попадают в указанный диапазон. Получив пары mid-date, из второй копии таблицы получите полные записи.

Comment: `То есть из варианта выше необходимо получить mid 15 и 34`
А вы уверены в mid = 34?

Comment: Да mid = 34 тоже может входить, так как они не выше сегодня + 2 недели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Оконные функции](https://habrahabr.ru/post/268983/) позволяют добиться нужного результата, правда MySql их до сих пор не поддерживает.

Но может и хорошо, т.к. оконные функции работают дольше, чем несколько запросов. Тут несколько вариантов:

- использовать подзапрос
- 2 запроса поочереди
- использовать view или временную таблицу

Я опишу вариант с подзапросом:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `tasks` t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `mid`, MAX(`date`) AS `date`
    FROM `tasks`
    WHERE `DATE` > CURDATE() AND `DATE` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14) 
    GROUP BY `mid`
) t2 ON t1.`mid` = t2.`mid` AND t1.`date` = t2.`date`;
```

Обязательно использовать индексы для `mid` и `date`. В данном примере мы сначала выбираем нужные даты по уникальным `mid`, а потом получаем все остальные данные.

**UPD**

Что-бы `mid` 34 тоже входил в выборку в условии предиката `WHERE` убираем выражение `DATE > CURDATE() AND`

**UPD2**
По замечанию @Akina перечитал вопрос и понял, что результат все таки должен быть другим. В вопросе упоминается максимальная дата группировки, а не просто дата. Правильный запрос:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `tasks` t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `mid`, MAX(`date`) AS `max_date`
    FROM `tasks`
    GROUP BY `mid`
    HAVING `max_date` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14) 
) t2 ON t1.`mid` = t2.`mid` AND t1.`date` = t2.`max_date`;
```

Comment: Попробуйте свой запрос на приведённых данных. mid=20 попадёт в выборку, хотя не должна.

Comment: Да, конечно же буду пробовать. Логика понятна, далее я уже думаю разберусь

Comment: @Akina не уверен, что не должна. По логике автора – должна. В самом вопросе логика и пример результата немного не сходятся

Comment: 20 не должна входить, так как там есть дата выходящая за диапазон сегодня + 2 недели (2017-02-07). Во всех остальных mid дата не выходит в большую сторону, а значит нам подходит. Немного не корретно объяснил первоначально...

Comment: @korytoff, поправьте свой запрос и переместите проверку на диапазон времени в HAVING. Тогда запрос будет соответствовать заданию.

Comment: @Akina на каком основании вы сделали такое предложение? Во-первых это не задание, а вопрос. А во-вторых автор уже ответил

Comment: _на каком основании вы сделали такое предложение?_ Во-первых, это очевидно. Во-вторых. увидев Ваш вопрос, я не поленился и выполнил все три запроса - Ваш исходный, Ваш откорректированный согласно UPD и модифицированный по моему предложению. Только последний дал тот результат, который просил автор. _это не задание, а вопрос_ Согласно тексту от автора, "Стоит задача выбрать строки" - слова "задача" и "задание" ближе, чем "задача" и "вопрос". _автор уже ответил_ Если автор спросил не то, что хотел - тут я уж ничего не могу сказать. P.S. Цитату с консоли прилагаю в форме ответа.

Comment: @Akina да, вы правы. Прочитав еще раз вопрос автора понял, что результат не тот

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> create table tasks
    -> (id int,mid int,s int,e int,`date` datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into tasks
    -> (id,mid,s,e,`date`)
    -> values
    -> (1,15,1,3,'2017-01-17 00:00:00'),
    -> (2,15,1,4,'2017-01-24 00:00:00'),
    -> (3,20,2,6,'2017-01-23 00:00:00'),
    -> (4,20,2,7,'2017-02-02 00:00:00'),
    -> (5,20,2,8,'2017-02-07 00:00:00'),
    -> (6,34,3,5,'2016-12-31 00:00:00');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT t1.*
    -> FROM `tasks` t1
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT `mid`, MAX(`date`) AS `date`
    ->     FROM `tasks`
    ->     WHERE `DATE` > CURDATE() AND `DATE` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
    ->     GROUP BY `mid`
    -> ) t2 ON t1.`mid` = t2.`mid` AND t1.`date` = t2.`date`;
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
| id   | mid  | s    | e    | date                |
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
|    2 |   15 |    1 |    4 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |
|    3 |   20 |    2 |    6 | 2017-01-23 00:00:00 |
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT t1.*
    -> FROM `tasks` t1
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT `mid`, MAX(`date`) AS `date`
    ->     FROM `tasks`
    ->     WHERE /* `DATE` > CURDATE() AND */ `DATE` < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
    ->     GROUP BY `mid`
    -> ) t2 ON t1.`mid` = t2.`mid` AND t1.`date` = t2.`date`;
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
| id   | mid  | s    | e    | date                |
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
|    2 |   15 |    1 |    4 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |
|    3 |   20 |    2 |    6 | 2017-01-23 00:00:00 |
|    6 |   34 |    3 |    5 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 |
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t1.*
    -> FROM `tasks` t1
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT `mid`, MAX(`date`) AS `date`
    ->     FROM `tasks`
    ->     GROUP BY `mid`
    ->     HAVING /* `DATE` > CURDATE() AND */ MAX(`DATE`) < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14)
    -> ) t2 ON t1.`mid` = t2.`mid` AND t1.`date` = t2.`date`;
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
| id   | mid  | s    | e    | date                |
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
|    2 |   15 |    1 |    4 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |
|    6 |   34 |    3 |    5 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 |
+------+------+------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```