# mysql запрос к бд

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь сделать задание, не получается.

На данный момент имею такой запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.status, dpb.price, dp.id AS docid, dp.datetime, dp.price_type 
FROM `Product` p
JOIN `DocPriceBody` dpb ON dpb.product_id = p.id
JOIN `DocPrice` dp ON dpb.doc_id = dp.id
WHERE date(dp.datetime) = "2017-09-02" AND dp.price_type = 1
```

Само задание:

Нужно вывести список товаров с последней ценой на определенную дату по определенному типу цены. (Реализовать одним запросом).
Структура БД:

Product – товары (наименование, описание, статус)

- id
- title
- description
- status

DocPrice – документы. Содержит шапку документов. (номер документа, дапа создания, тип цены, статус). Статус документа 0 – цены не отображаются, 1 – цена отображается.

- Id
- datetime
- price_type (тип цены)
- status

DocPriceBody – таблица документов содержит список товаров и цену (товар, цена).

- Id
- doc_id
- product_id
- price

Примечание.
Создайте несколько документов с одним и тем же товаром и в запросе указывайте дату между документами. Так же учтите товар, который не имеет цены. т.е. не указан в документе, в списке тоже должен отображаться.

Есть идеи?

Comment: По хорошему можно было бы сделать что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496532/194569 или более стандартными методами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616042/194569 т.е. выполнить еще join с подзапросом, в котором выбрать максимальные даты меньшие заданной сгруппированные по product_id

Comment: @Valera, постарайтесь уделить внимание в вопросе, тому что именно у вас не получается и с каким именнусловием в задаче у Вас возникают проблемы, чтобы отвечающие не тратили лишнее время на анализ Вашего решения. Опишите, что Вы хотели сделать, что сделать получилось и что еще хотелось бы, но Вы не знаете как.

Comment: Или вот очень похожий вопрос с решением с IN вместо join. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624551/

Answer (score 0):

Разобрал на подусловия.
Есть 2-а подзапроса, выполняют необходимые действия.

Если возможно, как их лучше совместить в один не теряя их свойств?
    - Пробую соединять их также через LEFT JOIN.

- 1-ый подзапрос:
  Выбирает все поля из product которых нет в других таблицах( docprice, docpricebody )- т.е. не имеют цены,
  используется оператор LEFT JOIN + условие WHERE (  WHERE docpricebody.product_id IS NULL )

  ```
       SELECT product.id, product.title, product.description,
       docprice.datetime, docprice.price_type, docprice.status,
       docpricebody.doc_id, docpricebody.product_id, docpricebody.price 
       FROM 
         product 
               LEFT JOIN docpricebody ON( product.id = docpricebody.product_id ) 
               LEFT JOIN docprice     ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id )
       WHERE 
           docpricebody.product_id IS NULL
  ```
- 2-ой подзапрос:
  Выбирает все необходимые поля со связующей таблицы:
  по "типу цены"

  - по определённой заданной( максимальной ) "дате"
  - с последней "ценой" на эту дату

    ```
     SELECT docpricebody.product_id, product.*, docprice.* 
     FROM docpricebody, product, docprice 
     WHERE docpricebody.doc_id IN( 
                                    SELECT dp1.id 
                                    FROM docprice dp1 
                                            INNER JOIN ( 
                                                SELECT MAX(docprice.datetime) AS max_date, docprice.price_type, docpricebody.product_id 
                                                FROM docprice 
                                                        INNER JOIN docpricebody ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id ) 
                                                GROUP BY docpricebody.product_id 
                                                HAVING max_date <= date('2017-09-20') AND ( docprice.price_type = 'закупочная')
                                            ) dp2 ON ( dp1.datetime = dp2.max_date )  
                                ) 
             AND docpricebody.product_id = product.id  
             AND docpricebody.doc_id = docprice.id
    ```
- Есть общий, тестирую, но результат не точный.

  SELECT  product.id, product.title, product.description,
            docprice.datetime, docprice.price_type, docprice.status, 
            docpricebody.doc_id, docpricebody.product_id, docpricebody.price 
            FROM 
              product 
                  LEFT JOIN (

  ```
                       SELECT docpricebody.product_id \n".
                       FROM docpricebody, product, docprice 
                       WHERE docpricebody.doc_id IN( 
                                          SELECT dp1.id 
                                          FROM docprice dp1 
                                                  INNER JOIN ( 
                                                      SELECT MAX(docprice.datetime) AS max_date, docprice.price_type, docpricebody.product_id 
                                                      FROM docprice 
                                                              INNER JOIN docpricebody ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id ) 
                                                      GROUP BY docpricebody.product_id 
                                                      HAVING max_date <= date('2017-09-20') AND ( docprice.price_type = 'закупочная')
                                                  ) dp2 ON ( dp1.datetime = dp2.max_date )  
                                      ) 
                      AND docpricebody.product_id = product.id  
                      AND docpricebody.doc_id = docprice.id 

              ) dpb ON ( dpb.product_id = product.id ) 
              LEFT JOIN docpricebody ON( product.id = docpricebody.product_id ) 
              LEFT JOIN docprice     ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id  ) 

        WHERE 
           docpricebody.product_id IS NULL 
           OR dpb.product_id IS NOT NULL
  ```